# Why do I get reports of java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError from Market

Tags: android, crash, report, google-play, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a app in the Android market and in its crash reports I get 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError crashes and everytime it is  for different .so file.

errors looks like

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load *****: findLibrary returned null
```

or

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: alloc_mem_region[871]: OOPS: 116 cannot map library ********. no vspace available.
```

or

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ******: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
```

It looks like some devices can not find some .so files.. The crash is not for any particular .so file. I have around 4 .so files in my app and sometimes it crashes for 1 and sometimes it crashes for another.

I could never reproduce this issue while testing, though I tested on almost all versions of Android...

Any pointers would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Think it would help if you showed how you link it

Comment: Just System.loadLibrary("mylibrary"). As I have already mentioned in most of the devices there are no issues.. but still i get some reports from market..

Comment: I have not yet able to sort out this issue but have got an added information that moving the app to sd card resolves the issue on some devices... devices I found are mostly HTC devices like HTC Wildfire S...Any pointers?

Answer (score 5):

I've seen similar issues myself – this seems to be affecting a very small number of users, and I can't directly correlate it to device types or operating systems. From the research I've done, however, I've found a discussion on the [Cyanogenmod Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=5374#c2); to quickly summarize: it sounds like some builds of that mod have not precisely copied some changes Google made to system-level libraries, meaning that some symbols (`__android_log_print`, for example) could be causing errors including causing your library to fail to load.

I'm in the process of trying to pin this down further, but I thought I'd share what I have to date.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the phones and/or the android versions that produce this problem?

What's the size of the libraries? Maybe you are hitting some memory limits of older phones while loading the libraries?

Comment: That could be one of the reason... As I said I could not reproduce on any of the devices I have and Android market logs does not give device information...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you alloc too much memory in libxxxx.so

"Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: alloc_mem_region[871]: OOPS: 116 cannot map library ********. no vspace available."

Answer (score 0):

I was getting reports from the Market about `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, even though my app was working fine in the emulator and on few android devices I have for testing. At some point I opened the generated .apk archive and noticed that few of the `libs/<ABI>` folders are missing one of the linked libraries I use (`.so` file). It turned out that Android devices with arm64 capable CPUs will load some of the linked libraries and crash when they can not find arm64 version of one of the libraries my app uses (instead of falling back to arm7v).

Similar issue with more details is explained here:
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#couldnt-load-librealm-jniso

Long story short, I added additional configuration in my build.gradle, that excludes arm64:

```
android {
  ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
  }
}
```

As a side note - arm64-v8a CPUs are compatible with arm-v7a instruction set and they can run 32-bit Thumb instructions, but mixing 64 and 32-bit libraries is not allowed.